# C# How create a button to cancel sleeping Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, window, task

I try to grasp how to create a button for to cancel a Task.
Here is my code, but it doesn't cancel the task:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CancellationTokenSource CTS;
    CancellationToken CT;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CT = CTS.Token;
        btnCancel.Click += btnCancelling;
        btnDoWork.Click += btnDoingWork;
    }

    private void btnCancelling (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CTS.Cancel();
    }

    private void btnDoingWork (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DoWork (CT);
        } catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            foreach (var inner in ae.InnerExceptions)
            {
                if (inner is TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The task was cancelled.");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }


    }


    private void DoWork (CancellationToken CT)
    {
        Task task = new Task(() =>
          {
                  Thread.Sleep(5000);
                  MessageBox.Show("WorkIsDone");
                  CT.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();          
          }, CT);
        task.Start();
    } 
}
```

DoWork() method works fine and it shows a Message "work is done" after sleeping for 5 sec.

I've read very diligent other similar topics on StackOverflow, but they are about calling Cancel() from the Main() method, but how to create a special button to do this job?

How I should modify my code to cancel a DoWork() method during sleeping?

Comment: Don't schedule a thread pool thread to sit there and do nothing for 5 seconds.  That's pointless.  If you want to send a letter to someone else tomorrow do you go hire someone to sit around for a day doing nothing and then put a letter in the mailbox, or do you just go about your day for a day and then put the letter in the mailbox the next day?

Comment: "How I should modify my code to cancel a DoWork() method during sleeping?" -- You can't. The cancel works by you explicitly viewing the token and if it's cancelled you explicitly return (or throw the OperationCancelledException). If you want to be able to cancel while doing work then you have to interrupt that work to check cancel. For your sleep example you could do something like: `var count = 0; while (count < 5) {  CT.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); Thread.Sleep(1000); count++; } MessageBox.Show("WorkIsDone");`. Note how I only sleep for 1 second and check cancel inbetween.

Comment: @Quantic That still leaves the same underlying problem.  You should fix the underlying problem and not schedule a new thread to sit there doing nothing for extended periods of time.  It's not a productive thing to do in the first place.  When you use the correct tool for the job, the problem goes away.

Comment: @Quantic Ok, I try to rephrase: suppose 'doWork()' is responsible for loading a Very_Large_File. It takes a while. Like in Windows, and any OS, every process has cancel button. I want to give an user a tool for cancel a loading by clicking 'Button btnCancel'. How I should implement such task?

Comment: @Servy doWork() just simulate a process, suppose doWork is  responsible for loading a Very_large_file, what takes a while. In this scenario did I chose a wrong tool as well?

Comment: @Vick.GV How you go about cancelling it is going to depend on what it is, if it can actually be cancelled, when it can be cancelled, and how you can go about actually cancelling it.

Comment: You can't cancel or "kill" a task, as far as I know. You can only cancel cancellable method calls; I mean the method itself must allow for a mechanism to cancel. `Thread.Sleep()` has no mechanism for cancel, and your hypothetical `DoWork()` method has no mechanism for cancel, so you cannot cancel it. *You* explicitly can create a method that is cancellable, `while (doingWork) { if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { return; OR cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); }}` is the [common pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to cancel the task during those 5 seconds of sleep. Cancelling will only occur at the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` call and only if the `CTS.Cancel()` call had already been made.

Your task code is the one who needs to stop work and check the token for cancellation from time to time.

You seem to be confused about how cancellation works. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)'s some basic info.